# Why don't particles move with my armature?

Tags: rigging, particles, armature

Hey I'm new to Blender and I tried rigging a lion with rigify with a tutorial but somehow it moves really weird. The mesh of the lion in Pose Mode moves with the armature but somehow the particles/the material won't move with it. Do I have to connect something or what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution and maybe another beginner will have the same problem so I'm going to explain what I did:
-> Go to your Modifier Properties and place your Armature above all Particle Settings you have so that it really affects all of them
-> Then check the box "Use Modifier Stack" (Particle Properties->Emission->Source) for all your particles.
Should work now!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I find that keeping the armature modifier at the top of the stack is a good practice in general. For example, it's my understanding that if a subdivision surface modifier is placed above it, the number of subdivisions in the mesh can actually become altered in response to changes in bone positions. This may or may not cause much grief in practice. But it would probably not be good for performance.